# Android getPixel Color of a scaled bitmap

Tags: android, colors, pixel, getpixel

I want to get a color of a pixel of a scaled Bitmap. I tried:

```
imgView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
```

but I'll only get the message:

> Can't call getPixel() on a recycled bitmap

I don't want to touch the screen like in this article: [Get touched pixel color of scaled ImageView](http://android-er.blogspot.de/2012/10/get-touched-pixel-color-of-scaled.html)

My intention is to load an image and downscale it. After that I want to get all pixelcolors of the new image.

To scaledown the Image I use this code:

```
            // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = scaleDown(bitmap, 8,8, true);

            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imgView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
```

Maybe it is possible to get Pixelcolors of the ImageView?

Thanks!!

Comment: You are saving the new image as a raw image?

Comment: How can I save the new image as a ner raw image?

Comment: I was just asking if you save the image as a raw image.